# Adding a logo on top of background image

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to add a logo on top of a background that I have on my template site. The logo is either in between the background images, or it does not appear at all.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title> Group Coursework </title>
    <link REL="StyleSheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="example.css">
    
    <style>
     body,
 html {
   height: 100%;
 }

 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .bg-image {
   /* Full height */
   height: 100%;
   /* Center and scale the image nicely */
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
 }

 /* Images used */

 .img1 {
   background-image: url("https://images3.alphacoders.com/914/thumb-1920-914671.png");
   filter: blur(4px);
   -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
 }

 .img2 {
   background-image: url("https://hdwallpapersmafia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/baby-groot-playing-basketball-lk-3840x2160-1.jpg");
 }

 /* Center and scale the image nicely */

 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 }

 .header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .navbar {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 20px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   text-align: center;
   transition: .5s;
 }

 .navbar ul li {
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 10px 50px;
   color: white;
   font-size: 32px;
   font-family: cursive;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: 10px;
   transition: .5s;
 }

 li a,
 .dropbtn {
   display: inline-block;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rbga (0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   z-index: 1;
 }

 .dropdown-content a {
   color: black;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
 }

 .dropdown-content a:hover {
   background-color: grey;
 }

 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
 }

 .logo {
   position: relative;
 }

 .logo:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 15%;
   left: 50%;
   background-image: url("https://www.pngkey.com/png/detail/44-447166_cavalier-logo-with-sword-and-flag-cleveland-cavaliers.png");
   background-size: 100px 100px;
   background-position: 30px 30px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   opacity: 0.7;
 }

    
    
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="bg-image img1"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="bg-image img2"></div>
    <div class="header">


      <div class="navbar" id='nav'>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://google.co.uk">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://standard.co.uk">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="tutorial3.html">About</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript.void(0)" class="dropbtn">Sports Websites</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="https://www.nba.com">NBA</a>
              <a href="https://www.nfl.com">NFL</a>
              <li><a href="reviews.html" onclick="javascript:void window.open('reviews.html','1552802326220','width=1200,height=500');return false;">Reviews</a></li>
            </div>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>

</html>
```

I saved it all to html as it shows an error if seperated to html / css. All i want to do is have the logo to be shown on top 15% and center 50%. Any suggestions that might help ?

Comment: The position relative is the issue. Also you have some `background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;

}` just floating around in the style. Also having content after the `</body>` tag is illegal and there is no problem separating the style from the html that I can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `position: relative` from `.logo` because it is obscured by the existing background, which exists in a higher stacking context. Once you remove the relative positioning, the `absolute` pseudo content can  create elevate its stacking order in correct context.

In addition, to center the `.logo` better, you can't just place it `left: 50%`. You need to account for half of the width of the background image size, which is `100px / 2` or `50px`.

Therefore, the `left` value becomes:

```css
left: calc(50% - 50px);
```

**Demo**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title> Group Coursework </title>
    <link REL="StyleSheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="example.css">
    
    <style>
     body,
 html {
   height: 100%;
 }

 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .bg-image {
   /* Full height */
   height: 100%;
   /* Center and scale the image nicely */
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
 }

 /* Images used */

 .img1 {
   background-image: url("https://images3.alphacoders.com/914/thumb-1920-914671.png");
   filter: blur(4px);
   -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
 }

 .img2 {
   background-image: url("https://hdwallpapersmafia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/baby-groot-playing-basketball-lk-3840x2160-1.jpg");
 }

 /* Center and scale the image nicely */

 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 }

 .header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .navbar {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 20px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   text-align: center;
   transition: .5s;
 }

 .navbar ul li {
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 10px 50px;
   color: white;
   font-size: 32px;
   font-family: cursive;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: 10px;
   transition: .5s;
 }

 li a,
 .dropbtn {
   display: inline-block;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rbga (0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   z-index: 1;
 }

 .dropdown-content a {
   color: black;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
 }

 .dropdown-content a:hover {
   background-color: grey;
 }

 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
 }

 .logo:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 15%;
   left: calc(50% - 50px);
   background-image: url("https://www.pngkey.com/png/detail/44-447166_cavalier-logo-with-sword-and-flag-cleveland-cavaliers.png");
   background-size: 100px 100px;
   background-position: 30px 30px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   opacity: 0.7;
 }

    
    
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="bg-image img1"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="bg-image img2"></div>
    <div class="header">


      <div class="navbar" id='nav'>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://google.co.uk">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://standard.co.uk">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="tutorial3.html">About</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript.void(0)" class="dropbtn">Sports Websites</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="https://www.nba.com">NBA</a>
              <a href="https://www.nfl.com">NFL</a>
              <li><a href="reviews.html" onclick="javascript:void window.open('reviews.html','1552802326220','width=1200,height=500');return false;">Reviews</a></li>
            </div>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, as I commented... I vote to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced_ There is also a } too many before `}

 /* Center and scale the image nicely */`

Comment: @mplungjan I just noticed your comment. But I *can* reproduce the issue, and fixed it, so I'm not sure I follow your thinking here.

Comment: After OP does what is in my comment, the problem is solved. There used to be a 
 "Too localized" meaning "This question is only really useful for you"

Comment: I understand. I added a little extra in my answer about stacking context and positioning of the logo background image. Maybe OP will gain something useful by reading the full answer.

Comment: Sure - I am not criticising your otherwise completely relevant answer. I am just commenting that it is easily fixed with many dupes and as such not as relevant for SO since there are hundreds of similar (identical?) questions with the same answer

Comment: Thank you for your comments and help. I'm self learning this and spending a bit too many hours than I should so sometimes it's just good to ask. Apologies if there's dupes that I missed. Thank you.